# mysql keeps crashing corrupt databases

Tags: mysql, centos6, corruption, mysql5

I have been trying to solve this for about 8 hours now.

Due to unrelated issues, I had to remove mysql and re-install it. since then, mysql crashes and restarts every 2-3seconds with the below in the mysql log.

```
170425  3:52:53  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140306907342592 in file handler/ha_innodb.cc line 875
InnoDB: Failing assertion: cset == 0
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
19:52:53 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=8384512
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 338336 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/libexec/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x29) [0x850ca9]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x483) [0x6a4143]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0() [0x3010c0f7e0]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35) [0x3010832495]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x175) [0x3010833c75]
/usr/libexec/mysqld() [0x72d9db]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(dict_mem_table_add_col+0x20e) [0x76080e]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(dict_load_table+0x99e) [0x75c1be]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(dict_load_table_on_id+0x403) [0x75cf43]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(row_purge_step+0x39c) [0x7b383c]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(que_run_threads+0x55b) [0x7a278b]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(trx_purge+0x332) [0x7ccb32]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(srv_master_thread+0x708) [0x7c54c8]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0() [0x3010c07aa1]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x30108e8bcd]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
170425 03:52:53 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
170425 03:52:53 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
170425  3:52:53  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
170425  3:52:53  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170425  3:52:53  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 1 648020427
170425  3:52:53 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
170425  3:52:53 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.73'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
```

I have attempted several ways to repair the database including :

- myisamchk --silent --force --fast --update-state
  /var/lib/mysql/*/*.MYI
- mysqlcheck -u root -p --auto-repair -c -o
  --all-databases

When using mysqlcheck, it gives me similar error messages to below, and not every database is corrupted, but the ones that are, have a large number of corrupted tables,:

```
joomla.e6dh5_utf8_conversion
Error    : Unknown collation '#224' in table 'e6dh5_utf8_conversion' definition
error    : Corrupt
```

All with no success...As i have previously backed up my database's i thought i would "DROP" the corrupted databases, MYsql wouldnt even let me do that!!

Is there any one that maybe able to help?

- Centos - Centos 6.9
- MySQL - mysql-server-5.1.73-8.el6_8.x86_64

Comment: Can you show the output of `yum history`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database has `Unknown collation` error. This means that you have installed old version of MySQL than was used before crash.

You need install newer version of MySQL which is used before crash or the latest version MariaDB from [Percona's repository](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/installation/yum_repo.html).

Don't forget to remove old version of mysql before installing new version by command:

```
# yum remove mysql mysql-server
```

Comment: Well, after a nightmarish 24 hours, strangely enough, this worked. I thanks you very much.  Though I can figure out, previous to this mess, i had an up to date mysql server. and when i uninstalled it, MariaDB  or  Percona was not mentioned in my yum repo....  Thanks again, greatly appreciated...